# What is the best chess piece?

Tags: pieces

I'm new to western chess and am still learning the rules and how the pieces perform.

What is generally considered the best chess piece?

Comment: If you lose the king, you lose the game, so that's better to keep it, whereas the queen is the most powerful piece. That being said, I don't think so simple rules questions are really on-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: The one that delivers mate.

Comment: Hi Shogi Gun, welcome to the site.  I closed this question because it doesn't really fit the site.  Questions that can be found via google aren't really on topic.  As you learn more of the rules, however, feel free to ask other questions that you can't figure out quickly with google!

Comment: The best piece is the one that checkmates your opponent's king.

Comment: The word "best" in the question should I think be interpreted as "most valuable", so the question is really about the values of the western chess pieces. [Wikipedia has a list of different valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece_relative_value).

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes but the piece I consider to checkmate my opponent's king game after game is my *brain*....

Answer (score 5):

The queen has the most squares available to land on, I recommend you get well acquainted with the rules of the game in the [official FIDE Handbook](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=124&view=article)

Comment: On an empty board, or a knight may well have more squares, in the beginning position, for instance.

Comment: False. Black bear.

Answer (score 4):

This question is subjective as the "best" piece depends on many factors such as how active a piece is.

The most important piece is your `King`.

In most cases, the `Queen` is the most powerful.

As an example, a `knight` might be more powerful than a `Queen`, possibly in a position where you are going to promote your pawn, promoting to a `Queen` might end in stalemate, whereas, promoting to a `Knight`, would end in checkmate.

I urge you to do a search on `Chess Rules` or something similar like `Beginner Chess` and you'll find countless material.